# Installing Anaconda on Server

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a Unix server where I have Python3 installed. I ssh to the server from my mac.

I was wondering if it possible to install Anaconda and Jupyter (will come with Anaconda) on the server so that I can just pull up Jupyter on the server terminal and run codes on jupyter running on the server.

Is it possible? And if yes, could someone guide me to the right link?

Answer (score 14):

in a terminal on your remote server:

```
#download anaconda (change version if you want)
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh

# run the installer
bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86-64.sh

# so changes in your path take place in you current session:
source ~/.bashrc

#To run a remote notebook, replace XXXX with your choice of four numbers like 9191
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=XXXX
#copy the url that you get as a result
```

Then in your local machine, open up a terminal and write:

```
#XXXX is the port you specified in the previous step, YYYY is a local port, for example 9999 to keep it simple
ssh -f [USER]@[SERVER] -L YYYY:localhost:XXXX -N
```

Then copy the url from the previous step, paste it in a browser, since you used the same port, you don't have to change anything on the url

Comment: Getting this error when running on server terminal

ERROR: cannot verify repo.anaconda.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB’:
  Issued certificate not yet valid.
To connect to repo.anaconda.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Comment: Go to https://www.anaconda.com/download and copy the link to download the appropriate anaconda version, use that instead of repo.anaconda....

Comment: Problem is there is no link as such on the downloads page. If i choose Linux download and right click copy link doesn't copy the link. It starts downloading it

Comment: Ok I did copy the address of Linux download and then ran wget on terminal. 

It gives me this error : 

Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 584008163 (557M) [application/x-sh]
Anaconda3-2018.12-MacOSX-x86_64.sh: Permission denied

Comment: that you may fix by using sudo (as in sudo wget ...), or moving to a directory where you have permission to write files

Comment: I was able to download to local, scp to server and get it installed. But quick question. This anaconda is only available for me on server. I have colleagues who also have server access but they can't access it. Do they need to install their own Anaconda or is it possible we can get anaconda installed on server which is available for every user having account there? I asked admin to install using root permission, he did but it's not available to us. He installed under /opt directory. Do we all need to do some pathing or something? Sorry for noob questions

Answer (score 1):

you can download anaconda using:`wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` 
and install using: `bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

After that just source the path of Anaconda in `.bashrc` file, it should work.

To access jupyter notebook, you can use ssh and run notebook in your browser on your host. Steps are mentioned in this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh)

Comment: Can I access the same from remote windows machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install anaconda on your linux machine (Server) and manage the python environment. But if just need Jupyter hosted in a server, just install Jupyter only and start the service which will server Jupyter Notebook. Access Jupyter notebook using your browser on any other PC.

Make a google search that how to install anaconda on Linux machine (Centos/Ubuntu etc)
After installation run following command

```
conda info
```

and then configure the Jupyter and run.

Simple way (Install Jupyter on a server): [Install, Run, and Connect to Jupyter Notebook on a Remote Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-run-connect-to-jupyter-notebook-on-remote-server)

Comment: did this  wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86.sh 

Gave this error 

Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 543837797 (519M) [application/x-sh]
Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Strange you have to use ssh to connect to the http server jupyter is. Seems to be overkill and unnecessarily complicates things to a point where half of interested people give up. Doesn't seem to be very intelligent to create something and then make it as impractical to use as possible.