# Anaconda install on windows Server 2016 standard

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, jupyterhub

I'm looking to install miniconda or anaconda in a Windows server machine , version 2016 standard. The objective is to automate python scripts using the task scheduler in the VM  and if possible also being able to remote into a jupyter notebook initiated on server.

I'm unable to test it prior to install (NOQA) and was not able to find this on the documentation. I'm looking for best practices.

Should a specific version of anaconda be used for this effect or an install of jupyter hub on WSfL be more appropriate?

So far this is the best i could find on SO but example is shown on a Linux machine.
[Installing Anaconda on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226763/installing-anaconda-on-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Conda on your Windows server should be straight forward. 
Here a [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) for the installation.
Start the scripts using a .bat file like this sample

```
CALL conda activate my-env && python my-script.py
```

If you want, you can install Jupyter within your environment.
Instead of using WSL, you should prefer using Linux directly.

Comment: Why do you say he should prefer using Linux directly? And what is WSL?

Comment: WSL stands for "Windows Subsystem for Linux".
The installation under Linux is quite straight forward and the resource usage is better with less overhead.